# Web login analytics using R for finding retention rates

Tags: r

The user data that I have: 
`

```
User_id Signup_date Login_date
1        13/01/2015 14/01/2015
1        13/01/2015 15/01/2015
2        13/01/2015 25/01/2015
2        13/01/2015 27/01/2015
2        13/01/2015 03/02/2015
3        14/01/2015 25/01/2015
4        14/01/2015 28/01/2015
5        15/01/2015 07/02/2015
```

The final result I'd want to have is something like this:

```
Signup_date Total_signups week1_visit% week2_visit% week3_visit%
 13/01/2015             2           50          50           50
 14/01/2015             2            0         100            0
 15/01/2015             1            0           0          100
```

If I signup on Jan 1, and visit on Jan 12, Jan 13, Jan 18, I would be counted as visited in the 2nd week (Note: Jan 12 and 13 are part of the same week, so I get counted only once), visited in the 3rd week.

I am new to R and will be great if someone can help with this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you are using dates I would look into the lubridate package. You could assign each date a week number and then count the occurrences of each week number (if I understand your goal correctly).

Comment: @AlexDometrius That's correct. But in my case, I'd want to calculate the visit week from the signup date, which I guess is not possible with lubridate package?

Comment: Finding the difference between dates can be done in base R. I don't think I understand your issue. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You want the granularity of the Signup date to be by date but apparently  also removing duplicates by ID, but the visit date tally to be ever-by-week? And these are percentages?   This all seems incommensurable. I think you need to at the very least to make your desired result actually depend precisely on the test data, which it clearly DOES NOT at the moment.